# Nginx cache headers

Tags: caching, nginx

My nginx is returning the following response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Tue, 29 Aug 2017 12:52:34 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Connection: keep-alive
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=btj7eq897r10tl7br5pf97ttd4; path=/
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
```

I have no idea where does `Expires` and `Cache-Control` are being set, I checked the site's config on nginx and its not there...any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

OK that is set by PHP so it's fine:

https://andidittrich.de/2015/09/php-worry-about-some-magical-added-cache-control-header.html